# VMWare : Configure network settings during OVA file deploy

Tags: vmware, esxi

Is it possible to configure network settings **[ IP, Netmaks, Gateway, DNS , Hostname ]** during ova file deployment ?. Can someone guide me how to enable network settings prompt during ova deployment ?.

I can done this through ovf file deployment. But I can give only ova file to my customers. When customer deploy the OVA file, it would prompt/configure ip parameter settings in the console.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

hope the following links will answer your question:
https://communities.vmware.com/thread/323831

https://blogs.vmware.com/vapp/2009/07/selfconfiguration-and-the-ovf-environment.html